# How to add max length in input of semantic-ui-react?

Tags: semantic-ui-react

Max length is not working in Input of semantic-ui-react.

```
<Input {...input} type={type} size={inputSize} transparent={transparent} disabled={disabled}>
   <input data-selector={`${dataSelector}-input`} maxlength="2" />
</Input>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. The maxLength prop is not in the semantic ui documentation. Changing to camel-case is one of those things you are expected to 'just know' after working with React for a while.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing the capital

e.g. `maxLength="2"`

Comment: Yes correct, thank you, it was a very easy thing that I missed. Apologies for asking it here.